# Javascript works when visible, but not when display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, I have a code that hides tr elements with id, the function that's hide/show this tr is called on next button which is in visible tr as an div element. When I use `visibility = 'hidden'` and then `visibility = 'visible'` it works I can see in `DOM` that the element is changing his property, but when I use `display` from `none` to `table-row` it does not change from `none`. What is the best way to hide all `tr` with `id` that contains other elements that are `visibile:hidden` and when they're not hidden then show next `tr`

Comment: It's a cool story. But a question should include code that replicates your problem :) . Please add code and try to be more clear about what the problem is and what you want to achieve

Comment: Did you try display:block , instead of table-row?

Comment: @ThanveerShah — Why would they? It's a `<tr>` element. Do you have some reason to suspect that the `<table>` has been changed from `display: table`?

Comment: Sorry , I did not pay attention to that

Comment: Can you include the all of the code? You can edit this post and add a snippet, or add a https://codepen.io/pen